# VS2012 - Sudden Death

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a fairly consistent but random occurrence of sudden death in Visual Studio 2012.  This usually happens when I press F6 to build - VS will disappear without any message or warning.

The event log has this:

```
Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading   
from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation 
failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error 
reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an 
error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result,   RequestContext& requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext) \r\n    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
```

I suspect it may be some extension I have installed but I've removed all the latest one I've installed and it persists.

Anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: I removes all the extensions I had installed and left only the standard ones - it still dies.

Comment: Can you check what F6 is bound to? Check the keyboard bindings.

Comment: I am getting the same thing every time I try and attach to w3wp with the VS2012 debugger.  Did you ever figure out what was going on in your case?

Comment: This is ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE, certainly not a completely mysterious problem for a pipe.  Look for an environmental problem, misbehaving anti-malware first.

Comment: Getting the same issue on VS 2013 :(

Comment: Suddenly experiencing the same issue with VS2015. Not crashing, but it hangs indefinatly when building/rebuilding certain projects (sometimes). When switching to ReSharper Build, the building succeeds though. Strange phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad installation to me. Try running a repair on your Visual Studio 2012 installation by selecting the application name in Windows **Programs and Features** and clicking on the *Change* button.

Comment: I've recently replaced my hardware with a fresh install of everything so I don't this that's the problem.